# MVC 4 Validation for Recursive relationship using ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, recursion, validationattribute

I have an MVC project that has several recursive relationships in different models. See sample model structure below.

**For example:**

- `tileid and parentid` (a tile can be related to many tiles)
- `regionid and parentid` (a region can be related to many regions)

I would like to create an MVC `ValidationAttribute` called `PreventRecursiveParent` that was dynamic enough to use throughout the system regardless of the Model, which prevented the user from assigning the parentid on a Model, to itself. i.e. prevent an infinite loop between the parent and the child.

e.g.
A shortened sample Model would be as follows:

```
  public partial class Tile
  {
      public Tile()
      {
        this.ChildTiles = new List<Tile>();
        this.TileRoles = new List<TileRole>();
        this.TileCompanies = new List<TileCompany>();
      }

    [Key]
    public int tileid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tile Header")]
    public string tileheading { get; set; }

    //This is a recursive relationship where a tile can have a parent, but not itself.
    [PreventRecursiveParent]  //--> Attribute I would like to create <--
    [Display(Name = "Parent Tile")]
    public Nullable<int> parentid { get; set; }

    public virtual Tile ParentTile { get; set; }
}
```

This issue is not so much when the user creates the `Tile` as they are not able to assign the `parentid` at that point, but when the user edits the `Tile`.

When the user edits a `Tile` they can select a `ParentTile` from a list of tiles, and assign it to the currently selected `Tile`.

I would like to ensure that the `ParentTile` and therefore `parentid` cannot be the same as the `Tile` itself, but also use the same code throughout all the other recursive relationship Models.

Therefore my question is as follows:

- Can I use a generic attribute to attach to any `parentid` in a Model
  to
     prevent a user from assigning itself to itself, and if so how?

Comment: Sound like you just want a `[NotEqualTo("parentid")]` attribute that you would apply to `tileid` or `regionid` (or the other way around). [Foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have one if you dont want to write your own.

Comment: I have had a look at Foolproof and I think this would work. Thanks for the feedback :)